# How do I get the sub of a user that grants scopes during user consent?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-nodejs-client

What is a [sub](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/js-reference#credential)? It's "the unique ID of the user's Google Account" (quoted from Google).

I would like to get the sub for the Google Account of the user that has granted any/all of the requested scopes during [the user consent process](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#2.-obtain-an-access-token-from-the-google-authorization-server.).

A solution in either Node.js (server-side) or regular JavaScript (client-side) would be most favourable.

Is this possible? If so, how could I do this?

Comment: I am not sure what you want to achieve here. Could you please write more about the use case from a user perspective and the surrounding system?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do this (a few hours ago) by requesting to grant the 'oauth2/userinfo.profile' scope and getting `<Response>.data.id` from `oauth2.userinfo.get({});`.